# custom array keys for str_getcsv()

Tags: php, arrays, key

Is this iteration key by key the proper way of initializing custom named keys for my str_getcsv array values ?
Also is the unset() expensive or even necessary in this loop ?

```
<?php

$lines = file('csv/random.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{

        $temp = str_getcsv($value,'|');
        $csv[$key]['code'] = $temp[0];
        $csv[$key]['name'] = $temp[1];
        $csv[$key]['price'] = $temp[2];
        $csv[$key]['avail'] = $temp[3];
        unset ($temp);   
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Following the advice in comments the code looks neater and runs significantly faster now

```
$keys = Array('code','name','price','avail');
$file = fopen('csv/random.csv',"r");
            while(! feof($file))
            {
                $temp[] = array_combine($keys,fgetcsv($file,'1000','|'));
            }
            fclose($file);
```

The answer marked below is I believe a more professional implementation of this for those who have need of such.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Use `array_combine` to applys keys on your CSV rows.

Comment: `unset` is good practice.

Comment: @scrowler `unset` is a waste of time, since he's immediately reassigning the variable. He could do it at the end of the loop, but unless these are really long lines it hardly seems worth it.

Comment: Why aren't you using `fgetcsv()` instead of reading the whole file into memory?

Comment: @Barmar yep - should be called at the end of the loop, good practice to unset variable which potentially could contain lots of data

Comment: Penny-wise, pound-foolish: unsetting `$temp` but not `$lines`.

Comment: @scrowler Based on the names of his columns, I'll bet it's at most 100 bytes.

Comment: Haha true, I wonder how true the filename would be though...

Comment: hah .. spot on guys. 
Mario thx i'll check into that.
@Barmar and scrowler i'll definately move/remove that unset as applying this good practice all over the code now..naaah.
The lines are short indeed, filename is !true.
I don't know why i used str_getcsv ... fgetcsv seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/SplFileObject) class:

```
<?php

$file = new SplFileObject('csv/random.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY
    | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
$file->setCsvControl('|');
$data = array();

foreach ($file as $row) {
    $data[] = array_combine(array('code', 'name', 'price', 'avail'), $row);
}
```

You have to be sure that your CSV lines have 4 different fields to use `array_combine()` this way. Note that this will give you all your CSV fields as strings. If you want, for instance, to have *code* as integer, *name* as string, *price* as float and *avail* as integer for each row, you can replace the `foreach` with that:

```
foreach ($file as $row) {
    $data[] = array_combine(
        array('code', 'name', 'price', 'avail'),
        array((int) $row[0], $row[1], (float) $row[2], (int) $row[3])
    );
}
```

To apply int/float conversions you can even use the [fscanf()](http://www.php.net/splfileobject.fscanf.php) method to read lines:

```
<?php

$file = new SplFileObject('csv/random.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE 
    | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
$data = array();

while ($row = $file->fscanf('%d|%[^|]|%f|%d')) {
    $data[] = array_combine(array('code', 'name', 'price', 'avail'), $row);
}
```

Comment: wow this is a pretty robust and fail-safe solution, I used the combination of advices from comments before tho as my csv and script are used in a controled enviroment where i can afford the loosness of the code. never the less this is THE answer !